# How do I calculate the Euclidean distance between a point and a list of points in Python?

Tags: python, list, distance, points

```
def findDistance((x1,y1),p) # finds Euclidean distance
```

Let's say p is `[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 1)]`,

```
x1 = 0

y1 = 0
```

Optional, you can define a radius.
The radius is 1 by default.
The result should only include those points that lie with `radius` of `(x1, y1)`:

```
findDistance((0, 0), punten)
```

[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]

Comment: When the radius is 1, you'll get this result.

Comment: [When you tried solving this yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), with which part of the solution did you get stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will find the (Euclidean) distance between `(x1, y1)` and every point in `p`:

```
In [6]: [math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2) for x2,y2 in p]
Out[6]: [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951]
```

If you only want points that lie within a certain distance from `(x1, y1)`, you could write:

```
In [8]: [(x2,y2) for x2,y2 in p if math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2) <= 1.0]
Out[8]: [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
```

Here, `1.0` is the desired radius.

To put it all together:

```
import math

def filter_points(points, origin, radius=1.0):
  x1, y1 = origin
  return [(x2,y2) for x2,y2 in points if math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2) <= radius]

p = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 1)]
print(filter_points(p, (0, 0), 1.0))
```

N.B. It's worth bearing rounding issues in mind: points that lie very close to the boundary might end up being misclassified. Whether it's important, and how best to deal with this depends on what you intend to do with the results.

Comment: Replace `math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2) <= radius` with `(x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2 <= radius**2` and you won't need to `import math` and your code will be faster.

Comment: @eumiro: It will, but it will also produce incorrect results if the caller were to specify a negative radius. I know this can be specifically handled, but my point is that one should be careful when proposing optimizations of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> p = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 1)]
>>> orig = (0, 0)
>>> map(lambda point: ((point[0]-orig[0])**2 + (point[1]-orig[1])**2)**(0.5), p)
[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951]
```